# Google Play Upload Error 16.03.2014

Tags: android, google-play

I just now upload apk,image to google play within says;

"We could not save your changes. Please try again."

Are you getting this error on uploading to Google Play?

Thank you for reply

Best Regards,

See Error -> [image]

---

I'm getting the same error when uploading apk
See Error ->  [image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play Store functioning and not programming.

Comment: you should simply try later

Comment: Firstly thank you for response,  I get  this error since 15 hours

Comment: I'm getting the same error when uploading apk...Upload failed.We could not save your changes. Please try again.

Comment: try contacting their support. Didnt occured for me before

Comment: There is a related bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67226

Comment: I'm having the same problem all day, I'm in the Netherlands.

Comment: Same here, in Israel. Tried different apks and different computers/connection. The bug is at google :(

Comment: Same in Greece...
i have the same problem... i feel you dude!! :(

Comment: Google is aware; from the Developer Console:
**Errors uploading to the Google Play Developer Console:**
We're currently aware of an issue impacting some developers attempting to upload APKs or Images to the Google Play Developer Console. We're working hard on a fix, and will provide an update once the issue is resolved. **[Link is here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4639475)**

Comment: http://ibrahimbalic.com/2014/android-os-memory-corruption-bug/ - seems this man has broken Google Play.

Comment: I now have the same problem (

Comment: Have the same problem.

Comment: having same problem, anyone fixed already?