# Cannot upload APK to google play

Tags: android, upload, google-play, apk

Cannot upload APK to google play.
Already tried other browsers and PCs. In no was it is possible to upload.

Always get:

> Upload new APK to Production
>       Upload failed
>       We could not save your changes. Please try again.
>       Upload another APK

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437316/google-play-upload-error-16-03-2014

Comment: I also face the same issue yesterday. In my case package name in the manifest file is different than applicationId in app gradle file.

Comment: I faced this issue too, when I'd successfully uploaded bundles for the past year. I'm not sure the issue, but I switched from using Chrome to Firefox, and the bundle uploaded 1st try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems to be something on Googles Part. A quick search shows that a lot of people is having this issue right now, me included.

EDIT 2014-03-17:
Seems like this is still a issue for a lot of people, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67226
Still no word from Google though as far as I know.
EDIT 2:
Seems to work fine for me now. Not sure if it will persist or even work for others.

Comment: Yeah, but this persists for more than 48 hours now. Something must be really broken on Google's part.

Comment: 2019 Mar 13: Issue occurred today again. Creating new release, changing browser didn't help. If I did anything new, it was the format of versionName/ version (versionCode is correct, it incremented as usual)

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy Same issue here today. Creating new release, changing browser didn't help. Maybe we should all contact the Google Console Support, and let them aware the issue......

Comment: @MnS thanks for confirming the same. Im also logging bug, please you also log the bug here, so things will be fixed sooner: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=submitting

Comment: This is happening to me too! App updates aren't going through

Comment: I face this problem with upload apk file to release as beta version too. Changing browser does not help.

Comment: @limmouyleng -- I raised the bug, I got an email reply from google, they fixed it, the bug is for last 24 hours, hopefully, yours is also fixed.

Comment: @MnS my issue is fixed, see resolution here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55154141/984471

Comment: @ManoharReddyPoreddy thanks man! good to hear your issue is fixed, I can upload the build as well, but seems like we need to make sure we clear all the cache or cookies before upload it~

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was telling me upload failed and to please try again.

In the network tab I could see the upload failing and retrying in a loop

**I logged out and back in and I could upload the .apks**

For more troubleshooting view here
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9061737?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but it might be helpful to someone.

In my case there was no problem of chrome/safari browser, After archive i got 2 apks out of which, i was uploading "xxxx-Signed.apk" so it was giving error like 'We can not save your changes. Please try again.' later i uploaded 2nd "xxxx.apk" and it uploaded successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Hope helpful: My Upload failed today app currently targets API level 25 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 26.

I have added in config.xml the below line then uploaded succesfully.

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />
```

Answer (score 0):

2019 Mar 13 issue occurred.
2019 Mar 13 issue got resolved.

The issue was on Google side.
This is confirmed by googleplay-developer-support@google.com

Followed the below steps:

- Raised a bug here:

  - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/publishing?extra.IssueType=submitting
- They have responded. And the issue is fixed for me.
- But, if you still have issue, then do the below as given by googleplay-developer-support@google.com

  - Raise here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050 as given by
  - Chat here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/?hl=en#contact=1&topic=3450769

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have uploaded the wrong apk, which was still in artifact library, So I deleted that and then upload the correct apk with the correct version it solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you increased version code and still its showing same error then log out google play console and login and try again it will work 100%

Answer (score 0):

Please for those who still thinking it's from google part but didn't try the cleaning solution yet, please give it a try:

This worked for me after many days of searches..
I completely uninstalled my browser (Firefox in my case)
I made sure nothing about the browser remains in my system following this ->[how to completely remove firefox from ubuntu](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiq-avX7NfvAhWEonEKHTs1AHcQFjABegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F16758%2Fremoving-firefox-in-ubuntu-with-all-add-ons-like-it-never-existed&usg=AOvVaw1S5McwFuA-PuY4Uf0_KhwD)

then I re-installed the browser and logged in to my playstore console
This really worked . I'm able to upload .apk as well as .aab