# unable to upload .aab/apk file to play store

Tags: android, console, apk, store, playback

Since google have changed the play store console view, I've got problems uploading my .aab/apk files. I've cleared caches, removed browser data and cookies, I have also used the private browsing in both Chrome and Safari and nothing works. The uploading indicator keeps spinning for a while and then gives the following error: "*`Couldn't upload file. Try again!`*" ugh :(

If someone experiencing the same issue or have a way to fixing this. Please share!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no information to help debug. Reach out to Play developer support.

Comment: This question may have your answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443497/cannot-upload-apk-to-google-play